How do sorted lists and their "Young Diagram" duals relate in their spectra? Are the spectrums dual in any sense?
Is there anything known about the properties of the fourier transform relative to a sorted list of number's dual via young complement? I will give an example:
[3,2,2,1]
=
...
..
..
.
=
[4,3,1]

See, you create a row with $x_i$ dots where $x_i$ is the $i$th number in your reversed sorted list. Now the dual is the length of the columns. In this case [3,2,2,1] mapped to [4,3,1].
Now consider the map $\beta(\{x_i\})$ which sends [3,2,2,1] to [1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1], that is, each integer $x_i$ gets sent to the list [1, $(x_i-1) \text{ zeros}$], and all of them get concatenated together. $\beta(\text{dual of $X$}) = $[1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1] in this example case.
Now if $X=\{x_i\}$ is dual to $\tilde X = \{\tilde x_i\}$ via this correspondence, what can we say about the Fourier transform of the images of $X$ and $\tilde X$ under $\beta$? It seems that they should be connected in some kind of way.
$$ X \to^{\text{Fourier Transform}(\beta(X))}\to F(\beta(X))$$
$$ \tilde X \to^{\text{Fourier Transform}(\beta(X))}\to F(\beta(\tilde X))$$
$$ X \to^{\text{Young dual}} \to \tilde X \to^{\text{Young dual}} \to X$$
My question is, what is known, if anything, about how $F(B(X))$ and $F(B(\tilde X))$ are related to $X$ and $\tilde X$? Can we use the fact that the dual of a dual is the original? Is that encoded in the spectrum, or somehow encoded when we have both Fourier objects as an algebraic constraint?  What all can be uncovered here, it seems that the fourier transforms of the "expanded" vectors should be related. At least they are the same size to start, but what more can be uncovered here?
Are the spectrums dual in any sense, or could they share hardly any relation at all? Just two completely different spectra for a list and its dual doesn't seem likely. Surely they must be related in a way deeper than simply "the image of $X$ and the dual $\tilde X$ under $\beta$ have the same size".
